# Missing user rights assignment entries for many security policies in list exported via secedit

Tags: windows

I want to modify the user rights assignment for a local security policy. In the GUI, find User Rights Assignment as follows: Win+R -> Enter "secpol.msc" -> Go to Local Policies -> Go to User Rights Assignment.

So, to modify a particular use rights assignment **via a script**, I need to export the INF file using secedit, modify it and then configure using the modified file using secedit. To export the INF file, I am using:

```
secedit /export /db C:\Windows\security\database\secedit.sdb /mergedpolicy /cfg SecPolicy.inf /log sec-policy.log /quiet
```

Now, the problem is that the INF file exported doesn't have all the user rights assignments that I see in the GUI. For example, the policy "Restore files and directories" has users/groups in its settings but it doesn't show up in the INF file. In fact, most don't. Only five do and all these five have a different symbol next to them in the GUI. How are these policies different? What do I need to do to export all the policies?

Thanks!

-Rohan.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you trying to export the security policy for?

There's a known issue (and hotfix) in Windows XP. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889532